# BigQuery convert a column in dictionary format to two columns and multiple rows

Tags: sql, dictionary, google-bigquery

I have a table with a dictionary in one column. Something like:

```
product   |  dict_discounts 
   A      | {"May":0.03, "June":0.1, "July":0.001}
   B      | {"May":0.002, "June":0.003, "July":0.01, "August":0.2, "September":0.5}
```

How do I change it to the following format?

```
product   |  month       | discount
   A      |  May         | 0.03
   A      |  June        | 0.1
   A      |  July        | 0.001
   B      |  May         | 0.002
   B      |  June        | 0.003
   B      |  July        | 0.01
   B      |  August      | 0.2
   B      |  September   | 0.5
```

So far I have found `SPLIT` but doesn't seem to be the easiest to use here. I got to

```
SELECT 
     product,
     dict_discounts_values

FROM table a,
UNNEST(SPLIT(a.feature_value, ',')) AS dict_discounts_values
```

giving

```
product   |  dict_discounts_values     
   A      |  {"June":0.1      
   A      |  "July":0.001   
   .
   .
   .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT product, 
  SPLIT(discount, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS month,
  SPLIT(discount, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS discount
FROM your_table,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(dict_discounts, r'[{} "]', ''))) discount
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]